# How to convert string "ABCD" to string "A:1,B:1,C:1,D:1" in Hive

Tags: hive

How to convert string "ABCD" to string "A:1,B:1,C:1,D:1" in Hive? Once I get "ABCD" in form of "A:1,B:1,C:1,D:1" my goal is to then convert it to map using str_to_map function. The number is fixed to 1, so there is not going to be any other number. But length of string can vary and any alphabets might appear there. No duplicates. Another example is:-

```
Input string is "PKWQADT" 
Desired output string is "P:1,K:1,W:1,Q:1,A:1,D:1,T:1"
```

My end goal is to then call this function on the modified string:-

```
str_to_map(modifiedstring)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the closest I could get:-

```
hive> select concat_ws(":1,",split("ABC",""));
OK
:1,A:1,B:1,C:1,
```

And then by applying str_to_map on top of it:-

```
hive> select str_to_map(concat_ws(":1,",split("ABC","")));
OK
{"":"1","C":"1","A":"1","B":"1"}
```

It almost looks desired output. It would be great if I could get rid of blank key.

Comment: regexp_replace does the trick, select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(':1,A:1,B:1,C:1,',',$',''),'^:1,','');
OK
A:1,B:1,C:1

Comment: Last comma may be left as is. So one call to regexp_replace is ok

Comment: I figured that for my needs the blank key really doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not efficient but works:

```
select str_to_map(concat(concat_ws(':1,',collect_set(a_col)),':1')) as a_map --collect_set returns array then concat string from array using ':1,' as a delimiter
    from    
           (select split('PKWQADT','') as a_array  --split array using '' as delimiter
              from dual
           )s lateral view outer explode(a_array) ar as a_col
     where ar.a_col<>'' and ar.a_col is not null --filter out first and last empty elements
    ; 


OK
{"D":"1","T":"1","W":"1","Q":"1","P":"1","A":"1","K":"1"}
Time taken: 48.246 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: efficiency is very important here. This logic is going to work on huge amount of data.

Comment: Then better not use join with lateral view and explode. Replace/substitute  strings after concat_ws using regexp...

Comment: select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(':1,A:1,B:1,C:1,',',$',''),'^:1,','');
OK
A:1,B:1,C:1